# Disable COD when exceeded specific amount

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, checkout

I need to disable Woocommerce COD option and make it unchecked when total price exceeded certain amount.

I tried this code, but does nothing!

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'unsetting_payment_gateway', 10, 1);
function unsetting_payment_gateway( $available_gateways ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $shipping_cost = WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total();
    $amount = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->tax_total + $shipping_cost;

  $max = 999.9 * WCPBC()->customer->exchange_rate;

    if($amount >= $max){   ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
          $("#payment_method_cod").disabled = true;
          $("#payment_method_cod").checked = false;       
        });       
    </script>    
    <?php
    add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'COD_exceed_amount_before_paying_notice' );
  }
    return $available_gateways;
}

function COD_exceed_amount_before_paying_notice() {
  wc_print_notice( __( 'COD amount exceeded!', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' );
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to remove any payment gateway.

Comment: why that javascript... I can see that you have gone to correct hook then why javascript ? When your condition is met, just unset the gateway...

unset($available_gateways['cod']);

I have got an article which explains it better - http://www.mingocommerce.com/showhide-payment-gateways-according-to-shipping-method/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should change your jquery code. Can you please try below code and check your code again. Because that is working for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {          
          $("#payment_method_cod").prop('checked', false);                 
          $("#payment_method_cod").attr('disabled', true);        
        });       
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways' , 'hide_payment_gateway', 20, 1);
    /**
    * remove cod gateway if cart total > 100
    * @param $gateways
    * @return mixed
    */
            
function hide_payment_gateway( $gateways ){
     //change whatever amount you want
     if( WC()->cart->subtotal < 699 ){
             
     // then unset the 'cod' key (cod is the unique id of COD Gateway)
     unset( $gateways['cod'] );
     add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'COD_exceed_amount_before_paying_notice' );
     }
     return $gateways;
}

function COD_exceed_amount_before_paying_notice() {
     wc_print_notice( __( 'COD option not available on orders below 699.00', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to deregister the woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js

Then include checkout.js in your theme assets folder and register it again after theme script files

then your code will work as you expect.

for deregister use below code,

wp_deregister_script( $handle );

again register by,

wp_enqueue_script(parameters);

Comment: I tried to dequeue and enqueue again woocommerce js but nothing changed. Maybe I didn't in wrong way! anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: not dequeue use deregister as i have already shown in my answer .In deregister only use id of checkout register script

Comment: but when using deregister, I have to register my js file, and it's a small modification, so I don't want to add a new js file to my theme.

Comment: this is what i was done when i got the same issue it is up to you